# How can I add additional elements to a DataTemplate in a ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my Xamarin.Forms XAML file, I have a list, and I'm using `ImageCell` inside of `DataTemplate` to display the items. So far I've figured out how to display two pieces of text and an image for each item, but I also want to add a button.

I tried putting something inside the `ImageCell`, but I got the following error:

> Can not set the content of ImageCell as it doesn't have a
>   ContentPropertyAttribute

I looked up how to use `ContentPropertyAttribute`, but the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ContentPropertyAttribute/) doesn't really explain how to use it.

How can I add additional elements to each `DataTemplate`?

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="Results">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding picture}" Text="{Binding name}" Detail="{Binding category}">
                    <Button Text="test" />
                </ImageCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Data in a ListView is presented in cells. **Each cell corresponds to a row of data**.

Since you want more data in a row than just what an `ImageCell` provides, you can use an `ViewCell` to construct what is displayed in your `ListView` row.

**Example:**

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image ImageSource="{Binding picture}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding name}" />
            <Button Text="Details" Command="{Binding DetailCommand}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use viewcell instead imagecell. And in viewcell u can use layout and there image, label and button

Comment: Can I do that right in XAML or do I have to do it in code-behind?

Comment: You can do that in xaml.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ImageCell`, you should go with `ViewCell` & add your custom elements in `ViewCell`.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="Results">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <ViewCell>
               <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee" Orientation="Vertical">
                   <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <Image Source="{Binding picture}" />
                       <Label Text="{Binding name}" TextColor="#f35e20" />
                       <Label Text="{Binding category}" TextColor="#f35e20" />
                       <Button Text="test" />
                   </StackLayout>
               </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```